# Parse variable number of differently typed integers from a line in C

Tags: c, parsing, arguments, scanf, fgets

I have a file with lines separated by '\n' where each line looks like either

```
10010 0 19 7 18
```

or

```
10014 -1 -1 -1 11 10db8 1
```

That is, every line will always either have 5 or 7 space separated values and the type of every value is also known beforehand. I want to read the file line by line and parse each line to extract inttypes (SCNi32, SCNu32, SCNx32..) and store in corresponding inttype variables. What is the easiest way to do this? I am new to C.

Comment: *Correct* way is to read the C library reference to find out what functions you need to use, and then use them. You seem to have a plan ready, just execute it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the line using `fgets()` parse the line by breaking the line into tokens.
2. Use `strtok()` to break the line into tokens.
3. Convert the token into integer using `atoi()` or any other string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a struct to store them in, for example:

```
typedef struct
{
  int16_t   a;
  uint32_t  b;
  int8_t    c;
  ...
} int_stuff_t;
```

Then you can just write a long list such as

```
#define GET_FORMAT_SPECIFIER(type) _Generic((type), \
  int16_t:  "%"SCNd16, \
  uint32_t: "%"SCNu32, \
  int8_t:   "%"SCNd8)

fscanf(fp, GET_FORMAT_SPECIFIER(int_stuff.a), &int_stuff.a);
fscanf(fp, GET_FORMAT_SPECIFIER(int_stuff.b), &int_stuff.b);
...
```

---

Now if you have a whole lot of these and they have all kinds of names and formats, then this might be one of the few valid cases where you should consider using X macros, to make the code easy to maintain.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <assert.h>

// X macro (type, name, format)
#define INT_STUFF_LIST     \
  X(int16_t,  a, SCNd16)   \
  X(uint32_t, b, SCNu32)   \
  X(int8_t,   c, SCNd8)

typedef struct
{
  #define X(type, name, format) \
  type name;
  INT_STUFF_LIST
  #undef X
} int_stuff_t;

int main()
{
  FILE* fp = fopen("something.txt", "r");
  assert(fp != NULL);

  int_stuff_t int_stuff;

  #define X(type, name, format) \
  fscanf(fp, "%" format, &int_stuff.name);
  INT_STUFF_LIST
  #undef X

  fclose(fp);
}
```

Though this is just a quick & dirty example, the real code should continuously check the result of each fscanf call to ensure it isn't EOF.